# Proper mySQL syntax for DELETE, FROM, WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a database with a table with 18 columns, the second of which is called "desc". I want to delete every row that has a certain value under "desc". I'm using this code:

```
DELETE FROM items WHERE desc='Swap this note at any bank for the equivalent item.'
```

Using this command inside of PHPMYADMIN gives me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc='Swap this note at any bank for the equivalent item.'' at line 1
```

I've looked around pretty well but I can't seem to find what I'm doing incorrectly.

mySQL version is 5.5, phpMyAdmin version is 3.4.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use backticks around `desc` as it is the keyword for descending order when using `ORDER BY`:

```
DELETE FROM items 
WHERE `desc`='Swap this note at any bank for the equivalent item.'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I didn't see that. Thanks for your help. I'm not getting any rows deleted, but the syntax is fine so I'm going to see what I did wrong otherwise. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I was using a single apostrophe, despite you saying back tick. Works fine now. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the back ticks. desc is a keyword in MySQL

```
DELETE FROM items WHERE `desc`='Swap this note at any bank for the equivalent item.'
```

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is a [RESERVED WORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL

in order to escape Reserved Words, you must use ***back tick*** ( ` )

```
DELETE FROM `items` 
WHERE `desc`='Swap this note at any bank for the equivalent item.'
```